# Show $\frac1{k-1}+\frac 6k-\frac{7}{k+1}=\frac{8k-6}{k(k^2-1)}$, deduce $\sum\limits_{k = 2}^n\frac{4k-3}{k(k^2-1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

> Prove that if $k > 1$, then
>
> $$ \dfrac{1}{k - 1} + \dfrac{6}{k} - \dfrac{7}{k + 1} = \dfrac{8k - 6}{k(k^2 - 1)}$$
>
> Hence simplify
>
> $$ \sum\limits_{k = 2}^n \dfrac{4k - 3}{k(k^2 -1)} $$

**My Work**

$$ \dfrac{1}{k - 1} + \dfrac{6}{k} - \dfrac{7}{k + 1} = \dfrac{8k - 6}{k(k^2 - 1)} = \dfrac{7k - 6}{k(k - 1)} - \dfrac{7}{k + 1}$$

$$= \dfrac{(7k - 6)(k + 1) - 7(k(k - 1))}{k(k - 1)(k + 1)}$$

$$= \dfrac{8k - 6}{k(k^2 - 1)} = 2 \left[ \dfrac{4k - 3}{k(k^2 -1)} \right]$$

$$\therefore \sum_{k = 2}^n \dfrac{4k - 3}{k(k^2 - 1)} = \dfrac{1}{2} \sum_{k = 2}^n \left( \dfrac{1}{k -1} + \dfrac{6}{k} - \dfrac{7}{k + 1} \right)$$

$$= \dfrac{1}{2} \left( \sum_{k = 2}^n \dfrac{1}{k -1} + 6 \sum_{k = 2}^n \dfrac{1}{k} - 7 \sum_{k = 2}^n \dfrac{1}{k + 1} \right)$$

$$= \dfrac{1}{2} \left( \sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1} \dfrac{1}{k - 1} + 6 \sum_{k = 2}^n \dfrac{1}{k} - 7 \sum_{k = 3}^{n + 1} \dfrac{1}{k + 1} \right)$$

I would appreciate it if people could please take the time to review my work and explain how I should proceed.

Comment: `matching the form` How is that a match? You can't just assume that $\,1/2 = 1\,$ and $\,7/2 = 3\,$.

Comment: @dxiv No idea. I just used pattern matching because I didn't know how to proceed. What would you suggest?

Comment: Just use what you got in the first step without any `pattern matching`, then see what "telescopes". P.S. Once again on MSE, I don't understand the reason why OP's question was summarily downvoted without even a comment why.

Comment: @ThePointer "pattern matching"? What's that? The line after "we get" is completely false! But observe: $$8k-6=2(4k-3).$$

Comment: $\sum\limits_{k = 2}^n \dfrac{4k - 3}{k(k^2 -1)} = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k = 2}^n \dfrac{8k - 6}{k(k^2 -1)}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k = 2}^n \left( \dfrac{1}{k - 1} + \dfrac{6}{k} - \dfrac{7}{k + 1} \right)$

Comment: I think$$\sum\limits_{k = 2}^n \dfrac{4k - 3}{k(k^2 -1)} = \sum_{k = 2}^n \left( \dfrac{1}{2(k - 1)} + \dfrac{3}{k} - \dfrac{7}{2(k + 1)} \right)$$

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will redo my work and edit the main post.

Comment: @AnuragA How can I simplify further from here?

Comment: Try writing out the first few terms of each sum explicitly - I would suggest not cancelling common factors when writing out sums like this because that can obscure patterns - keep the denominators as they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{k = 2}^n \dfrac{4k - 3}{k(k^2 -1)} & = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k = 2}^n \dfrac{8k - 6}{k(k^2 -1)}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k = 2}^n \left( \dfrac{1}{k - 1} + \dfrac{6}{k} - \dfrac{7}{k + 1} \right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k = 2}^n \left( \dfrac{1}{k - 1} + \dfrac{6}{k} - \dfrac{6}{k + 1}-\dfrac{1}{k+1} \right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\sum_{k = 2}^n \left( \dfrac{1}{k - 1} -\dfrac{1}{k+1}\right) +6\sum_{k = 2}^n \left( \dfrac{1}{k} - \dfrac{1}{k + 1}\right)\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)+6\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\right]
\end{align*}
In the last step, I am using the idea of a telescopic sum. I hope you can take it from here.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.